# How to save form data in React Native when we close the app?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

First, is it possible to listen an event when we are about to close the app so we can save it first?

I have read several post in Stackoverflow and it says it's not possible to achieve that.

I use dynamic form, I get the data from backend and will sending back the value.
So, how can I save my form data before killing the app? Oh by the way, I use redux.

Thank you

Comment: `componentWillUnmount()` might be the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best possible solution would be to save the form data whenever the user is done editing it using a [debounce function](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce).

Comment: I have 20 or more field. is it a good idea to save data every time user change the value?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, you are saving the data anyways.

Answer (score 0):

ithink you should something like sqlite database to save it local on the device
or you can save it in the local storage

Comment: Yeah but, if I save to local storage every time onchange is applied... is it a good idea? I mean I have 20 or more field that all required to be filled.

Comment: yes in every time you change it sert it again in the local storage